# Python - Find a tuple in list of lists

Tags: python

I have list of tuples (`mytuples`) and a list of lists (`mylist`).

I want to find how many times each tuple in mytuples occurs in every list.

Say tuple `(2,3)` occurs in `[1,2,3,4]`, `[2,3,4,5]` and `[2,3]`. Therefore count of `(2,3)` is `3`.

Tuple and list size can be different.

```
mytuples = [(2,3), (3,6), (1,2)]
mylist = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[2,3],[4,5,6]]

count={}    
for m in mytuples :
    counter = 0        
    for i in mylist :
        if set(m).issubset(i):
            counter = counter + 1
    count[m]=counter
```

My output would be `{(2,3):3, (3,6): 0, (1,2):1}`

This approach works fine but when my list size is huge say 1000 of records, it is more time consuming. Can this be done faster? any suggestions?

Comment: Is the order of the items in the tuple/list important?

Comment: Can you change the data structure, or only the algorithm? Usually the two should go hand in hand.

Comment: The list will always be in sorted order. Tuple can be in any order. And order does not matter.

Comment: @PeterWood i cannot change the data structure. Only the algorithm. But if speed can be increased by changing the data structure, then I can try that. But that being the last option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current algorithm can be made somewhat faster with a small adjustment:

```
# Your input data.
tuples = [(2,3), (3,6), (1,2)]
lists = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[2,3],[4,5,6]]

# Convert to sets just once, rather than repeatedly
# within the nested for-loops.
subsets = {t : set(t) for t in tuples}
mainsets = [set(xs) for xs in lists]

# Same as your algorithm, but written differently.
tallies = {
    tup : sum(s.issubset(m) for m in mainsets)
    for tup, s in subsets.items()
}

print(tallies)
```

Comment: This is even more faster than what was suggested by Anton vBR.

Comment: Your solution works good on a descent big list. I tried on a list of size = 541909 and tuples size = 3363671.. but it is running for last 30 mins. Can it be optimized more?

Comment: @Learner Nothing obvious jumps out at me. If you are dealing with data volumes on that scale, rather than trying to squeeze more optimization out of this algorithm, you might want to step back and see if your underlying problem can be solved with a different algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

**Using** dict comprehension we could reduce everything to one single-line.

And assuming the tuples are always pairs:

```
count = {(x,y):sum((x in i and y in i) for i in mylist) for x,y in mytuples}
# {(1, 2): 1, (2, 3): 3, (3, 6): 0}
```

Or you could sum using `all()` if tuple size is unkown:

```
count = {t:sum(all(x in i for x in t) for i in mylist) for t in mytuples}
# {(1, 2): 1, (2, 3): 3, (3, 6): 0}
```

---

**If this isn't clear:**

We go through multiple of these:

```
[all(x in i for x in (2,3)) for i in mylist]
# [True, True, True, False] 
# sum([True, True, True, False]) = 3
# And we assign them back to the tuple
```

Comment: This solution also reduced the time significantly.

Comment: @Learner Yeap, using sets is fast. I think my first solution was the fastest of them when I tried on a small set, however I upvoted FMc's solution too. Fast is nice but I prefer readability over fast when I use python.