# Python - Compare two lists to find the count

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, set

This is an extended question from the below link

[Python - Find a tuple in list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49598695/python-find-a-tuple-in-list-of-lists/49598770?noredirect=1#comment86205749_49598770)

I have been using the following solution

```
# Your input data.
tuples = [(2,3), (3,6), (1,2)]
lists = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[2,3],[4,5,6]]

# Convert to sets just once, rather than repeatedly
# within the nested for-loops.
subsets = {t : set(t) for t in tuples}
mainsets = [set(xs) for xs in lists]

# Same as your algorithm, but written differently.
tallies = {
    tup : sum(s.issubset(m) for m in mainsets)
    for tup, s in subsets.items()
}

print(tallies)
```

It works perfectly for the given solution but when my `lists size = 541909` and `tuples size = 3363671` it takes a lot of time. Its been running for `30 minutes` and I am yet to get the output. The elements in each list/tuple will be ascending order and I am ready to change the data structures of these elements. What would be the fastest way to do this operation?

Comment: @jpp It did speed up. That is why I upvoted the answer. Mean while I was waiting if anyone else can come up with even more faster solution.

Comment: Good to know. This kind of feedback is helpful because I may try and find a faster way :). We also don't have your data so can't know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some performance improvement by using `collections.defaultdict` to build the dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Your input data.
tuples = [(i, i+1) for i in range(1000)]
lists = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[2,3],[4,5,6]] * 1000

def original(tuples, lists):
    subsets = {t : set(t) for t in tuples}
    mainsets = [set(xs) for xs in lists]

    return { tup : sum(s.issubset(m) for m in mainsets) for tup, s in subsets.items() }

def jp(tuples, lists):
    subsets = list(map(frozenset, tuples))
    mainsets = list(map(set, lists))
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for item in mainsets:
        for sub in subsets:
            if sub.issubset(item):
                d[sub] += 1
    return d

%timeit original(tuples, lists)  # 707 ms per loop
%timeit jp(tuples, lists)        # 431 ms per loop
```